# Serial write not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, serial-port

I am trying to write the char "b" out the serial port on an iPhone using code example provided from [this tutorial](http://chrisrjones.com/KegCop/Jailbroken%20Serial%20Manual.html), but I am not getting the desired results.  When I use the serial console app provided from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/serialforios/home/Home/) it seems to be sending the letter / char "b" to the Arduino because my light starts blinking.

The method I constructed for the app that I am trying to send the "b" char looks like the following,

```
- (IBAction)blinkFlow_A_LED:(id)sender {

    // method to blink the Flow_A LED on the kegboard-mini Arduino sheild.

    NSLog(@"blink Flow_A btn pressed");

    NSLog(@"hello kyle");

    // open serial port / interface

    [serial open:B2400];
    if(serial.isOpened)
    {
        NSLog(@"Serial Port Opened");
    }
    else NSLog(@"Serial Port Closed");

    // print serial debugging messages
    serial.debug = true;


    // send serial data (tx)

    [serial write:text];

    // print message sent
    NSLog(@"the command sent was:%@",text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you defining 'text'?  Text should be NSString.

Eg:

```
[serial write:@"hello world"];
```